# Validación de uri con Joi

Tags: nodejs, url

Me gustaría pedir ayuda en lo siguiente, estoy tratando de guardar imágenes guardadas en firebase, lo que genera una uri muy larga, haciendo la validación con Joi.string.uri me arroja un error por el largo de la cadena, si le pongo un maxlenght igual no me permite guardar el dato, alguien ha trabajado este tema y me puede dar alguna idea? Cómo puedo guardar esta uri tan larga en mi base de datos usando Joi como validador?